# fluent nhibernate id start number

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am developing an application using Fluent NHIbernate. I was thinking about a small issue. Is Fluent NHibernate starting Id numberes from 0 or 1... What is the value of the (mapped) Id for the first element inserted into the database.

sorry for the noob question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its not Fluent NHibernate that will populate the value of first inserted row, its nhibernate and it depends on the [generator you configured](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx).

If you use identity or native, the first row its probably 1.

Comment: i am just maping Id(x=> x.Id)... so it will be 1